# Homescreen Widget with Ionic cordova and the cordova-plugin-ace

Tags: android, ionic-framework, widget, cordova-plugins, android-manifest

I want to ship an widget with my Cordova app. Currently i just use the Ionic 4 tabs starter project and have not changed any data on the src. I just added the ace-plugin and do the changes in the platforms and native folder (described at the bottom). I do some tutorial on creating an Widget (https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1218204/How-to-Create-an-Android-Application-Widget-using). But after all I have tried, the widget not occure in the wigetlist of my phone.

Widgets need to be written in native code, so i added the ace-plugin which add a folder named 'native'. In this folder the native code can be written and is then shiped to the platforms folder of cordova on building. Then i followed the tutorial from above and added the receiver and the service for an widget in the platforms Android Manifest and the native (ace) Android Manifest. The manifest was the only one, i changed in the platforms Folder. All other changes where made in the native folder of the plugin.
I provide the metadata for the widget in the res folder by adding the list_widget_info.xml and add the layouts for the list widgets by adding the list_widget_item.xml and the list_widget_layout.xml to the layout folder. Also i provided an Image in the drawable folder. As WidgetProvider i added the ListWidgetProvider.java to the src/io/ionic/starter folder.
After the build, everything in the native folder is shipped the right way to the platforms folder.

AndroidMaifest.xml (between the created activity and the 'Ace-activity'

```
<receiver android:name="io.ionic.starter.ListWidgetProvider">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
   </intent-filter>
   <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/list_widget_info"/>
</receiver>
<service android:exported="false" android:name="run.ace.AppWidgetService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS" />
```

ListWidgetProvider.java

```
package io.ionic.starter;

public class ListWidgetProvider extends run.ace.AppWidgetProvider {

   @Override
   protected int getLayoutResourceId(android.content.Context context) {
     return run.ace.NativeHost.getResourceId("list_widget_layout", "layout", context);
   }

   @Override
   protected int getViewResourceId(android.content.Context context) {
     return run.ace.NativeHost.getResourceId("list_widget_view", "id", context);
   }

   @Override
   protected int getItemResourceId(android.content.Context context) {
     return run.ace.NativeHost.getResourceId("list_widget_item", "id", context);
   }

   @Override
   protected int getItemTextResourceId(android.content.Context context) {
     return run.ace.NativeHost.getResourceId("list_widget_item_text", "id", context);
   }

   @Override
   protected int getItemLayoutResourceId(android.content.Context context) {
     return run.ace.NativeHost.getResourceId("list_widget_item", "layout", context);
   }
}
```

list_widget_info.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:minWidth="250dp"
  android:minHeight="40dp"
  android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
  android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
  android:previewImage="@drawable/list_widget_preview"
  android:initialLayout="@layout/list_widget_layout">
</appwidget-provider>
```

list_widget_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_widget_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_widget_item_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="40px" />
</FrameLayout>
```

list_widget_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_widget_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:loopViews="true" />
```

In my opinion it may be some error in the android manifest, because if there should be an error with the other files, the widget should been displayed in the Widgetlist, but not been usable.

My Questions are:

- has someone have the same problem by using the ace-plugin and know the solution to display the widget in the widgetlist?
- is there some error, i have not seen, maybe in the native Code to produce an widget?
- is my approach right, that this error should depend on the Android Manifest?
- can I show the android manifest somewhere after the run of my app on the phone?

I am happy about every hint i can follow to solve this problem. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: thanks i will try. because i want native feel in my application..

Answer (score 0):

So at least i have some improvements. I found out, that my Project do not really use the AndroidManifest in the platforms/android folder, however the one in the platforms/android/app . So therefore if i manually copy all the files i provide in the Question in the app folder, it works as in the tutorial expected.
Also i needed to import the file the plugins get added (cordova.js) in the index.html. Normally this should be generated with the create command ...

Also if i want to use a Listview in the Widget, the provides WidgetService to do this is not working for me. So i remove it from the AndroidManifest and use my own Service like one can do in a native App. Therefore the android.appwidget is not working, however i can also use it by invoking it 'manually'.

So well already i got the widget, but there are still some questions, why it needs to be in the platforms/android/app folder and is not used if i copy it outside of it...